# How to use a variable from method in another class?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have some problem with alert dialog... How I can call alert.show(); in Second class to call alert dialog ?

I need to show alertdialog onReceive method but I can't do that...

Can somebody help me with this ?

p.s. Sorry for my english.. ;|

***Main Class:***

```
    public class Main extends Activity {

    ...

     public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {

     ...


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("ALARM");
                builder.setMessage("Wstajesz czy dalej drzemiesz ?!");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Wstaje...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Do do my action here

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Spie!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // I do not need any action here you might
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                ....
    }
```

***Second Class:***

```
    public class Second extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {

         /* 
           -->  here i want to call an alert using: alert.show(); It's possible ?

         */
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't show a `Dialog` from a `Receiver`, you need an `Activity`. Either use an `Intent` to start your `MainActivity` or depending on what you want exactly, make it a separate `Activity` with a `Dialog theme`. You can do this by creating an `Activity` and declaring it in your `manifest` with a theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Note that you need to set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when creating your `Intent` from the `Receiver` to start an `Activity`